# DIDM Matching with Difference-in-difference using cross-sectional data

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, matching, cross-section

I need to know how can I combine in stata the DID (difference-in-difference) model with the PSM (Propensity score matching) with cross-sectional data. I had searched and there are tones of answers related to each of those models, but together I haven't been able to find them. Could someone please help me!! ??

Comment: The evaluation that I'm doing is if a policy has affected the health of the children.For it I have 3 cross-sectional data sets:with the first two(both are before the treatment)Im prooving the paralel tendencies needed to use the Diff-in-diff model. The 3rd data base is after de program, so my hope is to use it with the 2nd data base to see if there has been an effect. For this the equation that I have to use is the combination of PSM and diff-in-diff (treatment=D period=t w=sumatory of the weights attributed): [Y(t=1)-w(D=1,t=0)*Y(t=0)]-[w(D=0,t=1)*Y(t=1)-w(D=0,t=0)*Y(t=0)]

Comment: The best source so far that I found is a book by the World Bank "Handbook on Impact Evaluation Quantitative Methods and Practices". Despite some commands were too old, they are very easy to follow. And it has PSM-DID Stata command.